# Associate site to a hub site without being tenant admin. UI vs. PowerShell

Tags: pnp-powershell, hub-site

I am trying to achieve a hub site association using PowerShell. I have tried both **Add-SPOHubSiteAssociation** and **Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation** and the first method require to connect to the SPOService, which is an issue because the account I am using is not a tenant admin. The second method returns a

> *Add-PnPHubSiteAssociation: Fjernserveren returnerede en fejl: (403) Forbudt*

So clearly there is an issue with permissions.

However, in the Hub settings, I have added the account that needs to perform the association to the field "People who can associate sites with this hub". I have tested that the account is able to associate the site to the hub via the UI, but I cannot manage using PowerShell. Can anybody explain this - and perhaps come up with a workaround to achieve the association by scripting without being a tenant admin.

Thanks,
Lars Kohsel